# Find the probability of drawing at least one white ball

Tags: probability

A box contains m white and n black balls. Suppose k balls are drawn from the box. Find the probability of drawing at least one white ball.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to find the probability of the complement : of drawing no white balls at all.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P(\text{atleast 1 white}) &= 1 - P(\text{no white})\\
&=1 - \frac{n \choose k}{n+m \choose k} 
\end{align}

If no white balls are chosen, then we can choose $k$ balls from $n$ black balls in $n \choose k$ ways. Total number of ways of choosing $k$ balls from $n$ black and $m$ white is $n+m \choose k$

Comment: Can you explain further. So this involves permutation?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Added some explanation. Hope it helps